# Generic functions in Rust with limited, known types?

Tags: generics, types, rust

I'm writing some code in Rust which can work equally as well with `f64` and `f32`.

Attempting to convert this to use generic functions is quite involved; I need to declare the capabilities of the type on every use.

In practice, I only want `f32` and `f64` to be used. Is there a way to write generic functions that only apply to a set of known types?

I realize this goes against generic functions a little.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [the `Float` trait from the num crate](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.Float.html). You’ll have anything you need for both `f32` and `f64` **only**. Do not write your own trait if you don’t really need to.

Just add the crate `num-traits` into your `[dependencies]` section of your **Cargo.toml** file to be able to use that trait:

```
[dependencies]
# ...
num-traits = "0.1"
```

Comment: *for both `f32` and `f64` only* — this is only true at a specific point in time and with a specific set of crates. It's entirely possible for *anyone* to implement a type that implements the `Float` trait, and thus pass that into the function.

Answer (score 3):

The only tool that comes to mind for this is a `trait`, so your function would be:

```
pub fn f<T: MyTrait>(x: T) {...}
```

You could then implement `MyTrait` for `f32` and `f64`.  This is close, but there's a hole: callers can implement the trait on their own types.  You can't get around this by making `MyTrait` private, since Rust then complains that you're using a private type (`MyTrait`) in a public interface.

So close, but I don't think it's exactly possible!

Although I agree with the other answer about using an existing relevant trait, you would do it a bit like:

```
mod foo {
    pub trait MyTrait {}
    impl MyTrait for f32 {}
    impl MyTrait for f64 {}

    pub fn f<T: MyTrait>(x: T) {}
}

pub fn main() {
    foo::f(3f32);
    foo::f(3f64);
    // foo::f(3u64);  // doesn't work as u64 doesn't implement MyTrait
}
```

Comment: I'd actually think that a custom trait could be better, depending on the context. It all depends on how the value is used and what kind of methods are needed. A custom trait is simply a manifestation of [the interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Comment: Performing `fn sqr<T: MyTrait>(x: T) -> T { x * x }` errors out gives `error: binary operation \`*\` cannot be applied to type \`T\``

Comment: You also need to specify what other traits T needs to implement, eg `T:MyTrait+Mul<T>` to allow multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be ideal, but I accomplish this by using a trait and a macro.

For example, say we want this function to take either `f32` or `f64`:

```rust
fn sqr(a: f32) -> f32 {
    a * a
}
```

We can first put it in a trait:

```rust
trait Sqr {
    fn sqr(self) -> Self;
}
```

Then we make a macro for implementing it. The macro just takes a type, and implements the trait for that type:

```rust
macro_rules! impl_sqr {
    ($t:ty) => (
        impl Sqr for $t {
            fn sqr(self) -> Self {
                self * self
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Then we call the macro for `f32` and `f64`:

```rust
impl_sqr!(f32);
impl_sqr!(f64);
```

[Full example here.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=15b32ef30b08f3fc985fcd2d363191d2&version=stable&backtrace=0)